# Update MongoDB document with PUT from Node.js API

Tags: node.js, mongodb, rest, api, mongoose

I have a REST API written in Node.js using Mongoose to access the backend MongoDB database. I'm trying to change the value of a field in a document based on an ID field in document.

When using Postman to test the following code, I get an error: `Cannot PUT /v1/remove/00001`

```
//Cancel variation by ID
app.put('v1/remove/:id', async (request, response) => {
    try {
        var result = await variationsModel.findOneAndUpdate({ 'variationID': request.params.id }, {$set: { 'variationStatus': 'Cancelled'}}, { upsert: true, new: true });
        response.send(result);      
    } catch (error) {
        response.status(500).send(error);
    }
})
```

This is the DB model defined for the API...

```
const variationsModel = mongoose.model("variations", {
        "variationID": String,
        "custID": String,
        "projID": String,
        "variationTitle": String,
        "variationDesc": String,
        "variationStatus": String,
        "variationChargeable": String,
        "variationCost": String,
        "requireMaterial": String,
        "variationRequestor": String,
        "variationCreationDate": String,
        "variationImages": [
            {
            "imageId": String
            }
        ],
        "variationCategory": String
});
```

Can anyone please help?

Thanks!

Comment: do you see an errore in the logs or in your http response?

Comment: Thanks for your response... Just a 404 which prompted me to look at the path where I found the leading '/' was missing. Thanks for prompting me to take another look!